# How to get an error message if a form is empty (plugin: Post for site)

Tags: plugins, posts, forms, errors

I wonder if you intelligent friends can detect the problem in this code. I want the form to display an error message if it's empty. Now it just goes to my completed form page.

```
<?php 
/* * *
* Processed form data into a proper post array, uses wp_insert_post() to add post. 
* 
* @param array $pfs_data POSTed array of data from the form
*/
require('../../../wp-load.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

/**
* Create post from form data, including uploading images
* @param array $post
* @param array $files
* @return string success or error message.
*/
function pfs_submit($post,$files){
$pfs_options_arr = get_option('pfs_options');
$pfs_options = $pfs_options_arr[0];
$pfs_data = $post;
$pfs_files = $files;
//echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($pfs_data, true)."</pre>\n";
//echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($pfs_files, true)."</pre>\n";

$title = $pfs_data['title'];
$category = $pfs_data['cat'];
$postcontent = $pfs_data['postcontent'];

$name = (array_key_exists('name',$pfs_data)) ? esc_html($pfs_data['name'],array()) : '';
$email = (array_key_exists('email',$pfs_data)) ? sanitize_email($pfs_data['email']) : '';

$taxonomies = array();

$imgAllowed = 0;
$result = Array(
    'image'=>"",
    'error'=>"",
    'success'=>"",
    'post'=>""
);
$success = False;
$upload = False;

if ( !current_user_can('publish_posts') && $pfs_options['allow_anon'] && $pfs_options['enable_captcha'] ){
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = $pfs_options_arr['recaptcha_private_key'];
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
}
if ( !current_user_can('publish_posts') && $pfs_options['allow_anon'] && $pfs_options['enable_captcha'] && !$resp->is_valid ) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    $result['error'] = printf(__("Incorrect reCAPTCHA: %s",'pfs_domain'), $resp->error);
} else {
    //echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($pfs_files['image']['name'], true)."</pre>\n";
    if (array_key_exists('image',$pfs_files)) { 
        /* play with the image */
        switch (True) {
        case (1 < count($pfs_files['image']['name'])):
            // multiple file upload
            $result['image'] = "multiple";
            $file = $pfs_files['image'];
            for ( $i = 0; $i < count($file['tmp_name']); $i++ ){
                if( ''!=$file['tmp_name'][$i] ){
                    $imgAllowed = (getimagesize($file['tmp_name'][$i])) ? True : (''==$file['name'][$i]);
                    if ($imgAllowed){
                        $upload[$i+1] = upload_image(array('name'=>$pfs_files["image"]["name"][$i], 'tmp_name'=>$pfs_files["image"]["tmp_name"][$i]));
                        if (False === $upload[$i+1]){
                            $result['error'] = __("Något gick fel när bilden skulle laddas upp.",'pfs_domain');
                        } else {
                            $success[$i+1] = True;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $result['error'] = __("Fel filformat. Bara formaten (.gif, .png, .jpg, .jpeg) fungerar.",'pfs_domain');
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case ((1 == count($pfs_files['image']['name'])) && ('' != $pfs_files['image']['name'][0]) ):
            // single file upload
            $file = $pfs_files['image'];
            $result['image'] = 'single';
            $imgAllowed = (getimagesize($file['tmp_name'][0])) ? True : (''==$file['name'][0]);
            if ($imgAllowed){
                $upload[1] = upload_image( array( 'name'=>$file["name"][0], 'tmp_name'=>$file["tmp_name"][0] ) );
                //echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($upload, true)."</pre>\n";
                if (False === $upload[1]){
                    $result['error'] = __("Något gick fel när bilden skulle laddas upp.",'pfs_domain');
                } else {
                    $success[1] = True;
                }
            } else {
                $result['error'] = __("Fel filformat. Bara formaten (.gif, .png, .jpg, .jpeg) fungerar.",'pfs_domain');
            }
            break;
        default: 
            $result['image'] = 'none';
        }
    }
    if ( '' != $result['error'] ) return $result; // fail if the image upload failed.

    //echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($upload, true)."</pre>\n";
    //echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($success, true)."</pre>\n";

    /* manipulate $pfs_data into proper post array */
    $has_content_things = ($title != '') && ($postcontent != '');
    if ( !current_user_can('publish_posts') && $pfs_options['allow_anon'] ) $has_content_things = $has_content_things && ($name != '') && is_email($email);
    if ( $has_content_things ) {
        $content = $postcontent;
        if ( !current_user_can('publish_posts') && $pfs_options['allow_anon'] ) $content .= apply_filters('pfs_submittedby_text',"<p>Berättat av <a href='mailto:$email'>$name</a></p>");
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
            global $user_ID;
            get_currentuserinfo();
        }
        if (is_array($success)){
            foreach(array_keys($success) as $i){
                $imgtag = "[!--image$i--]";
                if (False === strpos($content,$imgtag)) $content .= "\n\n$imgtag";
                $content = str_replace($imgtag, wp_get_attachment_link( $upload[$i], $pfs_options['wp_image_size']), $content);
            }
        } 
        //if any [!--image#--] tags remain, they are invalid and should just be deleted.
        $content = preg_replace('/\[\!--image\d*--\]/','',$content);

        // $terms[{tax name}] = array(term1, term2, etc)
        if ( array_key_exists('terms',$pfs_data) ) {
            foreach ($pfs_data['terms'] as $taxon => $terms){
                if ( !is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxon) ) {
                    $pfs_data['terms'][$taxon] = implode(',',$terms);
                }
            }
        }

        $postarr = array();
        $postarr['post_title'] = $title;
        $postarr['post_content'] = apply_filters('comment_text', $content);
        $postarr['comment_status'] = $pfs_options['comment_status'];
        $postarr['post_status'] = $pfs_options['post_status'];
        $postarr['post_author'] = ( is_user_logged_in() ) ? $user_ID : $pfs_options['default_author'];
        $postarr['tax_input'] = (array_key_exists('terms',$pfs_data)) ? $pfs_data['terms'] : array();
        $postarr['post_type'] = $pfs_options['post_type'];
        $postarr['post_category'] = array($category);
        //echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($postarr, true)."</pre>\n";
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($postarr);

        if (0 == $post_id) {
            $result['error'] = __("Berättelsen kunde inte laddas upp - okänt fel.",'pfs_domain');
        } else {
            $result['success'] = __("Berättelsen är tillagd, du kommer att komma vidare om en stund.",'pfs_domain');
            $result['post'] = $post_id;
        }
    } else {
         $result['error'] = __("Du har lämnat en ruta tom. Alla rutor behöver fyllas i.",'pfs_domain');
    }
}
 return $result;
}

/**

* Upload images
*/
function upload_image($image){
$file = wp_upload_bits( $image["name"], null, file_get_contents($image["tmp_name"]));
//echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">";
//var_dump($file);
//echo "</pre>\n";
if (false === $file['error']) {
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($file['file']), null );
    $attachment = array(
     'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
     'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file['file'])),
     'post_content' => '',
     'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file['file'] );
    // you must first include the image.php file
    // for the function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() to work
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file['file'] );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
    return $attach_id;
} else {
    //TODO: er, error handling?
    return false;
}
}

if (!empty($_POST)){
$pfs = pfs_submit($_POST,$_FILES);
echo json_encode($pfs);
//echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($pfs, true)."\n";
wp_redirect("http://domda.se/tack/");
exit;
} else {
/* TODO: translate following */
_e('Den här sidan hade du inte behövt se, något är fel.','pfs_domain');
echo "<a href='".get_bloginfo('url')."'>" . __('Go home?','pfs_domain') . "</a>";
}

//get_footer();
?>
```

The support for the plugin isn't active. Sorry to say.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: How could that be useful for future visitors?

Answer (score 1):

You've already got a check for `$_POST` == empty.

```
**if (!empty($_POST)){
$pfs = pfs_submit($_POST,$_FILES);
echo json_encode($pfs);
//echo "<pre style=\"border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:5px;\">".print_r($pfs, true)."\n";
wp_redirect("http://domda.se/tack/");
exit;
} else {
/* TODO: translate following */
_e('Den här sidan hade du inte behövt se, något är fel.','pfs_domain');
echo "<a href='".get_bloginfo('url')."'>" . __('Go home?','pfs_domain') . "</a>";
}**
```

Add an error handler there. You will need to pass a parameter through `wp_redirect` ...

```
wp_redirect("http://domda.se/tack/?myerror=error-code");
```

And process it on the receiving page...

```
if (isset($_GET['myerror'])) {
  // do stuff
}
```